# How to install ol-cesium through npm and import in .ts file in open layers application

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers, cesiumjs

When I install OL-Cesium through npm and import in our .ts file its showing error.
you can see in image [click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTEzl.png)

so how to Good way to install ol-cesium and import this in .ts file without getting error
and I am also using open layers.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import LineString from 'ol/geom/LineString';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import {defaults} from 'ol/control/defaults';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import {XYZ} from 'ol/source';
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image';
import OLCesium from 'olcs/OLCesium';
```

**import OLCesium from 'olcs/OLCesium';**
this import file is shown error how to solve this error.